# How to install pyside2-uic in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, 16.04, pyside

You can install PySide2 like so:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:thopiekar/pyside-git
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python
apt-get install -y python-dev
apt-get install -y python-pyside2
```

But how do you install the `pyside2-uic` executable along with its dependencies (the `pyside2uic` Python module)?

Comment: The line `apt-get add-apt-repository -y ppa:thopiekar/pyside-git` should read `add-apt-repository -y ppa:thopiekar/pyside-git` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

- Install `pyside2-tools`.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install pyside2-tools
  ```
- Force `pyside2-uic` to run as a Python 3 script.

  - Manually edit `/usr/bin/pyside2-uic` as the superuser with your favourite religious-war text editor – in my case, `vim`.

    ```
    sudo vim /usr/bin/pyside2-uic
    ```
  - Edit the first line to read:

    ```
    #! /usr/bin/python3
    ```

*Voila!*

### wut?

Installing `pyside2-tools` *without* manually editing `/usr/bin/pyside2-uic` as suggested by [edwinksl](https://askubuntu.com/users/15003/edwinksl)'s [prior answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/826451/415719) results in a fatal exception on running `pyside2-uic`:

```
$ pyside2-uic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyside2-uic", line 28, in <module>
    from pyside2uic.driver import Driver
ImportError: No module named pyside2uic.driver
```

The reason why appears to be that the [PySide2 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/pyside-git) installs the `pyside2uic` package for Python 3 but *not* Python 2.

Even if this PPA *did* correctly install the `pyside2uic` package for both, however, the resulting `pyside2-uic` script would still only be usable by Python 2 users. Python 3 users would be hung out to dry. Since Python 2 is nearing its end-of-life, **that would be bad.**

Ultimately, the only viable long-term solution is for this PPA to provide two different packages:

- `python3-pyside-tools`, providing Python 3-specific PySide 2 utilities with Python 3-specific filenames (e.g., `/usr/bin/pyside2-uic-py3`).
- `python2-pyside-tools`, providing Python 2-specific PySide 2 utilities with Python 2-specific filenames (e.g., `/usr/bin/pyside2-uic-py2`).

Python 2 and 3 are two distinct languages. *You gotta keep 'em separated.*

Until that wondrous day, the above solution will have to do. Thanks for all the PySide 2 packaging, [Thomas Karl Pietrowski](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar) .

Comment: I get the following error, running `pyside2-uic` with `python3` on Ubuntu 16.04:
`ImportError: No module named 'PySide2'`
Also it seems pyside2 is not provided for python3 with this ppa.

Answer (score 3):

The `pyside2-uic` file is provided by the `pyside2-tools` package from the PPA you gave. Therefore, you install `pyside2-tools` using:

```
sudo apt-get install pyside2-tools
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on how to fix the following when you execute pyside2-uic? ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyside2-uic", line 28, in <module>
    from pyside2uic.driver import Driver
ImportError: No module named pyside2uic.driver``` I think it's because the `pyside2uic` Python module isn't installed.

Comment: That is odd. The `pyside2-tools` package does have `driver.py`, so the module exists.

Comment: Also, I noticed in your post you tried to install `python-pyside2` but I don't think that package exists in the Ubuntu repos nor in the PPA you are using. I think you meant to install `pyside2`, which is provided by the PPA. Maybe this is related to the problem you have; I am not sure.

Comment: I'm using this to differentiate between `python-pyside2` and `python3-pyside2` and [it seems to work well](http://pastebin.com/ygj7qHUP) eventhough [I see the package is called `pyside2` in the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/pyside-git). However, nothing besides the PySide2 module exists in my `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. If I attempt `apt-get install pyside2` I get ```Unable to locate package pyside2```. Hmmm... I really wonder what happened to the `pyside2uic` package.

Comment: I think I found what's causing issues for me: http://pastebin.com/UyCKiPRM

Comment: Hm, fixing that [clearly installs `pyside2-tools`](http://pastebin.com/rGQ1WEsp) without issues but there's no `pysideuic2` module to be found. Any ideas why?

Comment: @fredrik I now see why installing `python2-pyside` works, so what you did for that is correct. As for why there is no `pysideuic2` module, that is very intriguing. It is there is in the [`tar.gz` file](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/pyside-git/+files/pyside2-tools_0.0.0-0~201605121616~rev98~pkg4~ubuntu16.04.1.tar.xz) for `pyside2-tools`.

Comment: Indeed it is. That's odd.

Comment: @fredrik Oh, I think I know what happened. It is installed for Python 3, not Python 2. It looks like the `pyside2uic` provided by the PPA is only for Python 3, not Python 2. See if you find anything interesting at `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`.

Comment: Well, would you [look at that](http://pastebin.com/xRNguUJQ)! It's in the Python 3 dist-packages. Copying that into `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` made pyside2-uic work! Could you please add this to your answer and I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @fredrik Hmm, I am not sure if copying an ostensibly Python 3 package into the `dist-packages` for Python 2.7 is a good idea. Perhaps you can try using `pyside2uic` for a bit before we decide it actually works? :)

Comment: Sure. At least it looks like a pure-Python package. I'll give it a shot.